# Filtering out JavaScript while communicating with the server

Tags: html, javascript, traffic-filtering

the community!

I am trying to achieve to filter out (or disable) all JavaScript data from the HTML page before delivering it to the browser.

Disabling it in the browser doesn't suit me and I need to process it before.

Do you know which steps I can follow or which open-source software to check?

Comment: Which browser you use? I can suggest Tor browser which filter javascript and ensure highest privacy

Comment: As I understand JavaScript is on the Browser side. I want to be one level before and filter network traffic. Disabling it in the Browser doesn't mean for me anything. I don't want to deliver JavaScript to a browser (any).